# como buscar elementos especificos en una cola de objetos?

Tags: java, netbeans-8.2

hola buenas tengo una duda si lleno una cola con objetos y cada objeto tiene un id como puedo imprimir solos los id de cada objeto dentro de la cola ? esto es parte de una tarea y es obligatorio

el problema es que si talves ingresara el id a buscar por consola se me aria un poco mas facil comparar el id ingresado con el id de los objetos de la cola jeje, peroooooo pasa que una ves ingresados los objetos debo imprimir solo los id ejemplo o solo los nombres de cada objeto y la verdad no tengo ni idea de como podria hacer eso, agradesco cualquier ayuda.
no tienen que dejarme codigo con que me guien un poco me ayudaria bastante

mi cola la hice con Queue que es obligatorio y la enlace con una lista enlazada
pero nose si la lista enlazada sea la mejor estructura de datos

```
     Queue cola = new LinkedList();
```

Comment: Pues recorres la lista de objetos uno a uno y con ellos imprimes lo que quieres, el nombre, la id o la dirección de su amante. Da igual que sea una cola, una lista, un array, un set... siempre se hace igual (entre comillas, el código difiere de una colección a otra), iterar es iterar. Recorrer la colección, asignas tu objeto a una variable, accedes a lo que necesitas y continuas con el siguiente. Aprender a programar no es aprender a escribir código, es aprender a resolver este tipo de problemas. Si lo hacemos nosotros no aprenderás nunca, hazlo y si tienes un error concreto, pregunta por el

Comment: si si ovio ese era el punto tampoco queria que me pasaran el codigo si me das la idea no pasa nada me sirve